# How to reference standard HTML element types within React?

Tags: reactjs

In React, I can reference any component function, which is really helpful for cases where I want to conditionally use one component type over another. For example:

```
const Link = ({ text, href, external = false }) => {
  const LinkType = external ? ExternalLink : InternalLink

  return <LinkType href={href}>{text}</LinkType>
}
```

What I can't figure out is, how can I implement this same type of interface when my child components are simple HTML elements? Is there something like this?

```
const SomeComponent = external ? React.Component('div') : React.Component('span')
```

Comment: Just use their names as string: `const SomeComponent = external ? 'div' : 'span';`

Comment: Thanks Emile, I didn't managed to find that searching on my own. Voted to close as duplicate

Comment: It's buried in the [`React.createElement` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement), which is what is really called behind JSX. ;)

Answer (score -3):

Just like this:

```
const SomeComponent = external ? <div>Hey!</div> : <span>Hey!</span>;
```

Comment: This won't do the same thing as conditionally using a component *reference*. In other words, it removes the capability of doing `<SomeComponent />`, which is what the OP is doing.